# How do I check purchase history after delete and reinstall application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I am developing an application which will allow user to purchase using In App Purchase and I want to remove ads after purchase. I can purchase succesfully with code below

```
BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                        .setSku("android.test.purchased")
                        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                        .build();
mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(getActivity(), flowParams);
```

But I cannot see the result from queryPurchaseHistoryAsync when I open app again and call this method below.

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {

                purchasesList.size();
            }
        });
```

**purchasesList.size() == 0**

Is "queryPurchaseHistoryAsync" method cannot show test purchase or Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Is queryPurchaseHistoryAsync method check purchase after delete and install app again.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** queryPurchaseHistoryAsync method check purchase after deleting and installing the app again against particular user

```
mBillingClient.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(@NonNull BillingResult billingResult, @Nullable List<PurchaseHistoryRecord> list) {
            
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will give all purchase items.

```
mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(),
                            new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                                    listener.onSkuDetailsResponse(responseCode, skuDetailsList);
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score -1):

`mBillingClient.queryPurchases()` is all you need. Call it at every app start and, for example, every time your main activity resumes. This way your (reinstalled) app will eventually detect all user's purchases.